# Listview with setStackFromBottom and a SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to get my listview to populate from the bottom up (which is working), and when the user pushes up - it should refresh the list.

Currently the SwipeRefreshLayout implementation seems to be a pull to refresh, is it possible to convert it to a push to refresh so that it can be used in the way that I need it?

Comment: you mean when you push a button it refreshes?? but you still want the pull to refresh?

Comment: Hello Rod, thanks for the quick response. 
No, currently it only refreshes if I swipe all the way to the top of the list (since it is set to setStackFromBottom). Since it populating from bottom up - like a chat app - I need to push the screen up (swipe further down) to refresh it

Comment: I think the only way is to create a button and refresh it on click.

Comment: It's possible if I use a swipe down to refresh, why would it be so different if it's a swipe up instead?

Comment: Try to use like :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720532/how-to-implement-pull-down-to-refresh-and-pull-up-to-refresh-in-expandable-list